# Exchange 2010 - run command on mail receive

Tags: exchange-server

Does anyone know is there a way to make Exchange server 2010 execute some program upon mail receive for some mailbox ?

For example:

I have mails test1@example.com and test2@example.com

I want to execute program1.exe when mail arrives to test1@example.com
and execute program2.exe when mail arrives to test2@example.com

I have looked all options in Exchange management console, and didn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

I made something similar using EWS and powershell. You can download EWS 
[here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371)

Then you can create an script in powershell that use the Exchange web service

This is the example of my script:

```
$MailboxName = "mail@domain.com"
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP1)
$service.TraceEnabled = $false

$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("name","password", "domain")
$service.Url="https://mail.yourdomain.com.au/ews/exchange.asmx"

try{
$fldArray = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId[] 1
$Inboxid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$fldArray[0] = $Inboxid
$stmsubscription = $service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications($fldArray, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EventType]::NewMail)
$stmConnection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection($service, 30);
$stmConnection.AddSubscription($stmsubscription)
Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $stmConnection -eventName "OnNotificationEvent" -Action {

    foreach($notEvent in $event.SourceEventArgs.Events){    
        [String]$itmId = $notEvent.ItemId.UniqueId.ToString()
        $message = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($event.MessageData,$itmId)
        IF ($message.Subject -eq "execprocess"){
            Start-Process  "mybat.bat" 
        }            
    }    


} -MessageData $service

}catch [Exception] {
                Get-Date  | Out-File C:\logs\logError.txt -Append
                "Error : "+  $_.Exception.Message  
                }
Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $stmConnection -eventName "OnDisconnect" -Action {$event.MessageData.Open()} -MessageData $stmConnection
$stmConnection.Open()
```

Then, run the 2 scripts one for every account you need to monitoring.

See the original example here--> [Source](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/using-ews-streaming-notifications-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Exchange has no out-of-box way to do this. You might want to look at using Exchange Web Services (EWS) subscriptions in an external service to do this.

Comment: I looked at EWS and something similar could be done via it. but what I need is exchange to initiate the process...
with EWS there is other side that needs to "ping" exchange server and check werther there is new mails..

I need exchange to trigger action when new mail arrives.. if not by executing external program then at least by calling specific url

for example when mail arrives for test1@example.com to call http://somesrver.com/script.php?id=1
and for test2@example.com to call http://someserver.com/script.php?id=2

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: The only place you could run code in-process is with a Transport Agent. Every single message passes through the Transport Pipeline, so, you could potentially write an agent that would trigger this. I would have the agent ping a service on the box via LPC/WCF versus doing the work in-proc to limit your impact on the Transport service itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way I accomplished this is by writing a powershell script using outlook com objects to scan the inbox for certain criteria and execute a process based on what it finds.